# Unable to find documents

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

I have a code like this:

```
def getItems(): Future[List[Item]] =
    collection.find(BSONDocument.empty).cursor[Item]().
      collect[List](-1, Cursor.FailOnError[List[Item]]())
```

But it is not getting all the items in the collection. When I look in the shell I can see the item by doing this:

```
db.items.find({});
```

I also tried to swap Json.obj with BSONDocument.empty but it doesn't bring back the item in the collection.

I also tried to do this to see if the cursor code is wrong. I tried something simple:

```
  override def getItems(): Future[Item] =
    collection.find(Json.obj()).requireOne[Item]
```

This does not work either.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the result on `collection.find().collect()` ?

Comment: That is not valid code. It says no implicit found for parameter swriter

Comment: No Json serializer as JsObject found for type Unit. Try to implement an implicit OWrites or OFormat for this type.
[error]     collection.find().collect[List]()

Comment: You are mixing issue, JSON serialization and query. Focus on BSON.